# Keras one hot embedding before LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Suppose I have a training dataset as several sequences with padded length = 40 and a dictionary length of 80, e.g., `example = [0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 9, 22, ...]` and I want to feed that into a LSTM layer. What I want to do is to apply one hot encoder to the sequences, e.g., `example_after_one_hot.shape = (40, 80)`. Is there a keras layer that is able to do this? I have tried `Embedding`, however, it seems that is not an one-hot encoding.

Edit: another way is to use Embedding layer. Given the dictionary only contains 80 different keys, how should I set the output of Embedding layer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61633257/10375049

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for a pre-processing task, not something that is strictly part of your network.

Keras has a one-hot text pre-processing function that may be able to help you.  Take a look at [Keras text preprocessing](https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/).  If this doesn't fit your needs, it's fairly easy to pre-process it yourself with numpy.  You can do something like...

```
X = numpy.zeros(shape=(len(sentences), 40, 80), dtype='float32')
for i, sent in enumerate(sentences):
    for j, word in enumerate(sent):
        X[i, j, word] = 1.0
```

This will give you a one-hot encoding for a 2D-array of "sentences", where each word in the array is an integer less than 80.  Of course the data doesn't have to be sentences, it can be any type of data.

Note that Embedding layers are for for **learning** a distributed representation of the data not for putting data in a one-hot format.

Comment: Making it part of the network could be useful because one hot encoding the data increases the memory usage required by a factor of the dictionary size. For a large dictionary, it quickly becomes prohibitive.