# Can one-hot encoding be performed within a Keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I've been working on a project that works with a relatively large dataset and I've been facing problems when it comes to one-hot encoding the integer encodings. The output matrix is too big to fit on my ram.

I was wondering if it was possible to perform the one-hot encoding within the Keras model because the integer encoding does fit nicely as an array on my memory.

Comment: would you like to one-hot encode your X or your y ?

Comment: I would like to encode my X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make one-hot encoding inside your model:

```
X = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5])

inp = Input((1,), dtype='int32')
x = Lambda(lambda x: tf.one_hot(x[:,0], len(set(X))))(inp)
out = Dense(20)(x)

model = Model(inp,out)
model.compile('adam','mse')
print(model.summary())

model.fit(X, np.random.uniform(0,1, (len(X),20)), epochs=3)
```

Answer (score -2):

The Keras API provides a method `to_categorical()` that can be used to one-hot encode integer data. If the integer data represents all the possible values of the classes, then the `to_categorical()` method can be used directly; otherwise, the number of classes can be passed to the method as the `num_classes` parameter.

The code snippet below illustrates the usage of the method:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import to_categorical
### Categorical data to be converted to numeric data
colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "red", "blue"]

### Universal list of colors
total_colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "black", "yellow"]

### map each color to an integer
mapping = {}
for x in range(len(total_colors)):
  mapping[total_colors[x]] = x

# integer representation
for x in range(len(colors)):
  colors[x] = mapping[colors[x]]

one_hot_encode = to_categorical(colors)
```